# How do you delete a tag set?

Tags: custom-fields

How do you delete a tag set? I created a tag set and only really needed to create a new tag.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation covering Groups and Tags is here at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/

To view tags, go to: Contacts > Manage Tags (Categories) in the navigation menu.  A tag can be edited or deleted using the respective links in its row.  If it is a reserved tag, remember to first untick the reserved box.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running an older version of the CiviCRM, you won't see the delete links unless you right-click on the tag. It's nonintuitive and took me awhile to find that out.

Contacts > Manage Tags (Categories) > right click on the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Tags, scroll to find the name of the tag set you wish to delete, then click on the "Delete" hyperlink to the right-hand side of it.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this will be helpful to someone else.

The answer to "how do you delete a **tag set**?"

Before you can delete a tag set, you must delete all tags in that tag set, which can be done by following the answers others have given: *Contacts > Manage Tags (Categories)* > click on a tag and then click "Delete" on the right-hand side. Or use the CTRL key to select all the tags and then delete all of them.

Once you have deleted all of the tags in a tag set, then the title on the right-hand side will say "Empty Tag Set" and the delete option will be "Delete Set."